# what's $Df(A)(X)$ if $f(A) = \det(A)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

let's begin with the simple case where $A$ is just a $2\times2$ matrix

let $\begin{align} f :& \mathbb{R^{2\times2}} \to \mathbb{R} \\
& A \mapsto \det(A)
\end{align}$

I want to find the differential of this mapping if $A$ is invertible.

as a hint I was suggested to compute the following limit :

$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac1t [\det(I+tX) -1]$ where $X \in \mathbb{R^{2\times2}}$

the limit turns out to be just the trace of $X$

and since $\det(I) = 1 $ we have that $Df(I)(X) = Tr(X)$, right ?

so I guess now that if I want to find $Df(A)(X)$ for $A$ invertible I have to compute this limit :

$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac1t [\det(A+tX) -\det(A)] = \det(A)\lim_{t \to 0} \frac1t [\det(I+tA^{-1}X) -1] $

so $Df(A)(X) = \det(A)Tr(A^{-1}X)$, right ?

now in higher dimensions the last step wouldn't change and I guess that in the first limit the expression $[\det(I+tX) -1]$ would be something of the form $tTr(X) +t^2(\cdots) + t^3(\cdots)+\cdots$

so it's all cool but what if $A$ is not invertible ? the $\det$ being some sort of a polynomial would still be differentiable, right ? but how do you construct the differential in this case ?

Edit : my bad if $A$ is not invertible then $\det(A) = 0$ so I guess $Df(A)(X) = 0$ ? can someone confirm this ?

Edit 2 : at the end it all comes down to evaluating this : $$\lim_{t \to 0 } \frac1t \det(A+tX)$$ for $A$ non-invertible and $X \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_formula

Comment: $det(A)A^{-1}$ is actually the transpose of the matrix of cofactors of $A$. Hence you can rewrite $Df(A)(X) = tr(Com(A)^TX)$. Now $Com(A)$ is defined regardless of whether $A$ is invertible or not, so this makes sense even for noninvertible matrices. Moreover, $A\mapsto Com(A)$ is continuous because it's polynomial, and so is $A\mapsto Df(A)(X)$, and $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist in having an explicit formula in terms of matrix operations, there is a nice way to evaluate the derivative in terms of the colums of matrices. If you write $A=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ you can compute $D\det(A)(X)$ as 
$$\tfrac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\det(A+tX)=\tfrac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\det(a_1+tx_1,\dots,a_n+tx_n).
$$
Using multilinearity of the determinant, you can directly expand this and invertibility plays no role in the whole computation, to get 
$\sum_{i=1}^n\det(a_1,\dots,a_{i-1},x_i,a_{i+1},\dots,a_n)$. In particular, you see readily from this formula that $Df(A)(X)$ vanishes for all $X$ if and only if the rank of $A$ is at most $n-2$.